# Error building DependencyGraph: @providesModule naming collision:

Tags: android, react-native, git-bash

I have just started trying out React Native, after following the [getting started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content) tutorial and initiating my project I ran `react-native start` I receive the following error:

> Failed to build DependencyGraph: @providesModule naming collision:
>   Duplicate module name: ReactNative   Paths:
>   C:\Users\PV\Documents\ReactNative\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\ReactNative.js
>   collides with C:\Users\PV\Documents\ReactNative\package.json
>
> This error is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same
>   name accross two different files. Error: @providesModule naming
>   collision:   Duplicate module name: ReactNative   Paths:
>   C:\Users\PV\Documents\ReactNative\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\ReactNative.js
>   collides with C:\Users\PV\Documents\ReactNative\package.json
>
> This error is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same
>   name accross two different files.
>       at HasteMap._updateHasteMap (C:\Users\PV\Documents\ReactNative\node_modules\node-haste\lib\DependencyGraph\HasteMap.js:160:15)
>       at C:\Users\PV\Documents\ReactNative\node_modules\node-haste\lib\DependencyGraph\HasteMap.js:125:25

I get this error right after I initiated the project with `react-native init` which gives me a clean React Native 0.25.1, also when trying test version 0.26.0-rc `npm install --save react-native@0.26.0-rc` when I start React native I get the same error.

Windows 10 x64 - Android phone & emulator - Latest React Native 0.25.1